# What is the tbb/task.h header for, and where can I get it?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Trying to compile a plugin that sets joint positions, I get this error:

```
$ make
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/set_joints.dir/set_joints.cc.o
In file included from /usr/include/gazebo-1.7/gazebo/transport/transport.hh:3:0,
                 from /usr/include/gazebo-1.7/gazebo/gazebo_core.hh:23,
                 from /usr/include/gazebo-1.7/gazebo/gazebo.hh:20,
                 from /home/benjaminblumer/Dropbox/RoboticsResearch/WAMDatabase/WAM Model/set_joints.cc:10:
/usr/include/gazebo-1.7/gazebo/transport/Connection.hh:20:22: fatal error: tbb/task.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/set_joints.dir/set_joints.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/set_joints.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What is the tbb library and how should I install it?  I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit with Gazebo 1.7.1.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2578/what-is-the-tbb/task.h-header-for,-and-where-can-i-get-it?/) by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 175 on 2013-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Try to install libtbb (http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/)

`~$ sudo apt-get install libtbb-dev libtbb2`

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Vaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/171/daniel-vaz/) with karma: 305 on 2013-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-04-26**:
Thanks! Fixed the problem. Should this be added as a dependency for Gazebo?

**Comment by [Daniel Vaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/171/daniel-vaz/) on 2013-04-26**:
Yes, in page (I think that is the newest installation instruction) http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.6/install the tbb library is a prerequisite. Best regards.

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-04-26**:
It's only listed as a prerequisite for installation from source.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-04-26**:
See: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo-release/pull-request/8/added-libtbb-dev/diff

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-04-26**:
Great. Thanks.

**Comment by [Daniel Vaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/171/daniel-vaz/) on 2013-04-27**:
I thought you had compiled gazebo from the source. ;)

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-04-29**:
No worries. That was my old setup, but I just reformatted my machine and decided to go the binary route.